# mySQL updates. How to handle simultaneous user submits

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Say I have a variable:

`$variable = [mySQL query: get number of likes of a particular post];`

And then I update it:

`$variable++;
[mySQL update table with new variable: $variable];`

Pretty much just like any other update correct?

But what if there are ten users who simultaneously `likes` a post that initially has 2 likes? There would obviously be an error, trying to update the table. Instead of `12` there would be only `3` likes.

How to avoid this?

Comment: easy `update table SET likes=likes+1 where id='fish'` do it in the mysql

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of using SET